# jquery-each for hidding elements

Tags: php, jquery, each

i have two buttons

```
<div id="box1" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button id="1" aria-label="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
1 test button
</div>
<div id="box2" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<button id="2" aria-label="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
2 test button
    </div>
```

well, hiding them with two if-statements works

```
if( $.cookie('box1') === 'closed' ) { 
  $('#box1').hide(); 
} 

if( $.cookie('box2') === 'closed' ) { 
  $('#box2').hide(); 
}
```

for more buttons an each is better but this doesn't work - why not? :-| tnx

```
$('.close').each(function(id, element) {
    var id = $(element).attr('id');
    if( $.cookie('#box'+id) === 'closed' ) {
        $('#box'+id).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: additionally i use this https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: = $.cookie('name', 'value'); but that's not the problem the cookie works in this example i guess the problem is "id" - it never goes into the if-statement

Comment: Use `debugger`. What is `id`'s value?

Comment: id = this.id = 1 (first loop) and 2 (2nd) - that is ok - but it doesnt work ;)

Comment: @michael No, HTML 5 allows id's to start with a number

Comment: you mean instead of 'id="2"' i should use 'data-id="2"'? didnt worked too :( (of course also with .attr('data-id')

Comment: @Robert Although I would not recommend using a number as id, it's allowed in HTML 5.

Comment: why are you confusing things using id as the index of the object collection and the id property of elements? I would change the former one to just `i`, that is just the array index of the results of your selector.  It probably dosn't matter much for the code itself but it takes away from the readability of it and looks haphazard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( $.cookie('#box'+id) === 'closed' ) {
```

The problem is the `#` before `box`. This is a cookie, not an element's id, you don't need it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the # before  `if( $.cookie('#box'+id) === 'closed' ) {`

So, it should looks like this:

```
$('.close').each(function(id, element) {
    var id = $(element).attr('id');
    if( $.cookie('box'+id) === 'closed' ) {
        $('#box'+id).hide();
    }
});
```